# Check the data type of a map scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to write something to check the data type of a `Map`, for some reason, it is not working, can someone point what I am doing wrong Here is the code

```
def mapTest() {

  var map= Map(1->"abc",2->20,3->(1 to 10 toList))

  map.foreach(a=>{a match {case a:(Int,String)=>"Int,String";case a:(Int,Int)=>"Int,Int";case a:(Int,List[Int])=>"Int,List"}})
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Are you able to expand on the use case for your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your code, or a slightly-clearer version of it:

```
map.foreach {
  case a: (Int, String) => println("Int,String")
  case a: (Int, Int) => println("Int,Int")
  case a: (Int, List[Int]) => println("Int,List")
}
```

You'll see the compiler throws a warning for each of the cases:

> Warning:(66, 15) non-variable type argument String in type pattern (Int, String) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
>         case a: (Int, String) => println("Int,String")

This basically means that what you're trying to do (i.e. use pattern-matching to discover the type of an element in a map) is impossible, due to **type erasure**. The generic types of the Tuple's elements can't be matched. However, there's a simple workaround:

```
map.foreach {
  case (a: Int, b: String) => println("Int,String")
  case (a: Int, b: Int) => println("Int,Int")
  case (a: Int, b: List[Int]) => println("Int,List")
}
```

This matches the types of each of the Tuple's elements separately (using the Tuple's `unapply` method) which *can* be done to overcome type erasure.

**Note** that for the same reason, the last case only makes sure the types are `(Int, List[_])` - it would match lists of any type, not just `List[Int]`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to work around type erasue to get access to the runtime type by using things such as ClassTags, and TypeTags. [Sinisa Louc](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20) provides a great explanation of the differences between the different tags and where they can and cannot be used.

Let me rephrase your question to:

- > Can I create a map whose elements are Heterogeneous and do different things depending on this type?

This question is a bit tricky to answer with pure scala as as @Tzach Zohar mentioned it is not easy to match against a collection type in your map, e.g. differentiate between a Map[Int,List[Int]] and Map[Int,List[String]].

This is possible if instead you switch to working with a library that supports Heterogeneous collections types such as [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

Import various required libraries:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.record._
import shapeless.syntax.singleton._
import shapeless.labelled.{FieldType, field}
```

Create a HList using the ->> which creates these type safe key -> value pairs

```
val hmap =
    (1 ->> "hello") ::
        (2 ->> 2) ::
        (3 ->> true) ::
        (4 ->> (1 to 10).toList) ::
        (5 ->> List("this", "is","great")) ::
        HNil
```

Create a poly morphic function which extracts the type information:

```
object TypeInfo extends Poly1 {
    implicit def stringCase[F <: Int] = typeInfo[F, String]("String")
    implicit def intCase[F <: Int] = typeInfo[F, Int]("Int")
    implicit def boolCase[F <: Int] = typeInfo[F, Boolean]("Boolean")
    implicit def listIntCase[F <: Int] = typeInfo[F, List[Int]]("List[Int]")
    implicit def listStringCase[F <: Int] = typeInfo[F, List[String]]("List[String]")

    private def typeInfo[K <: Int, V](msg : String) =
      at[FieldType[K, V]] (_ => field[K](msg))
}
```

Now we can map over the values using the map function:

```
val typeInfo = hmap map TypeInfo
```

Now you can see all the different types we have extracted by:

```
typeInfo.values
```